# How can I tell whether the word following "to be" is an adjective or a past participle?

Tags: adjectives, past-participles

Is there any rule to know whether a word is an adjective or a past participle when it follows "to be"? For example:

> John is hurt.

The website where I found this sentence says that “hurt” is a **past participle** in a passive sentence.

> Are you hurt?

I found this sentence in my dictionary, which says that “hurt” is an **adjective**.

I feel confused. Is "hurt" an adjective or a past participle, and is it active or passive?

Comment: Recommended reading: http://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/adjectiv/particip.htm.

Comment: It took a while before I can find my old answer. Here it is: http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/16136/3281. Check out my tips for distinguishing the adjective and verbal usages.

Comment: Sometimes there's no motivation to make the distinction, and in those cases there's no need to choose one or the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, both statements are true. It's a *past participle* and an *adjective*. Strictly speaking it's a *participle adjective*, i.e. a participle used as adjective.

The most common participle adjectives like *hurt*, *bored*, *interested* are listed in dictionaries. So, let's take a look at an example where only the verb is listed in dictionaries.

> His face is scarred.

You won't find many entries in dictionaries for *scarred* as an adjective. However, it clearly functions as an adjective here. Similarly, you can also write:

> His scarred face ...

So, in your example *hurt* is both, an adjective and a participle and both your sources are correct.

Answer (score -1):

this has been covered well here i feel http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/13051-adjective-or-past-participle

edit
actually the link given by  Damkerng T is more comprehensive, my link is simple but not as full i.e. you can test by replacing the linking verb by an equals sign = and see if it still makes sense

so john=hurt, you=hurt both make sense and so hurt here is acting as adjectives

Comment: oh ok thx for lettting me know :) updated post