# How do I know whether the past participle form is an adjective or a passive verb?

Tags: adjectives, passive-voice, past-participles

A past participle can either be an adjective or a passive-verb form.

For example.

He was **excited** about the movie
(Here the world 'excited' is an adjective)

An adjective is **used** to describe a person
(Here 'used' is the passive-verb form)

How do I know whether the past participle form is an adjective or a passive verb for any sentence?

Comment: I think you are looking for a distinction that does not really exist.  You can just as easily say "He was excited **by** the idea of watching the movie." or "An adjective was used."  A past participle isn't "an adjective *or* a passive verb", it is its own thing.

Comment: The "very" test is useful. If the word can be modified by "very" it is certainly an adjective. And in examples with the verb "be", if be" can be replaced by "remain" the word that follows it is probably an adjective.

Comment: Related: [How can I tell whether the word following "to be" is an adjective or a past participle?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/20320/how-can-i-tell-whether-the-word-following-to-be-is-an-adjective-or-a-past-part)

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of this older question: [Adjective or verb?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/16127/adjective-or-verb)