# Usage of very/much with present/past participle

Tags: word-usage, exam-questions

I have a book which says that *very* is used before present participle  e.g. very interesting, very daring, very entertaining etc and *much* before past participle like much amazed, much grieved, much surprised etc.
Then the author has given few exceptions where *very* is used with past participle e.g. very tired, very dejected, very contented etc.

He has given a few sentences in exercise section for error correction. One of them is :

> Being much contented with the sincerity of the members of the staff, the chief minister said that the state needed sincere men like them.

As per him I need to replace *much contented* with *very contented* as it is from one of those exceptions.

My question is is there any other reason/ logic why *very* is used here not *much*, in other words Do I need to cram all those exceptions or there is any work around to find such errors in usage of much/very ?

Comment: Have you heard of [participial adjectives](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/16127/adjective-or-verb). Btw, the rule is quite nonsense to me.

Comment: *Very contended* is not idiomatic, at least not to my ear, so I'd take everything in the book with [a grain of salt](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/take-with-a-grain-of-salt.html).  That example sentence, for example, is simply horrible writing.   I expect he means "much contented" and not "much contended", as these are very different words ... but even so, it's still a mess.

Comment: This comment might be off-topic, but I think  you should shake the book off. See also [resources for learning English](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english)